# Get a file's ctime, atime, mtime and extended attributes

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, shell-scripting

I would like to display a file's ctime, mtime and atime along with whether it has extended attributes or not.
There are 2 commands that can do this but I have not been able to combine them into a single command to give a single line of output.

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -printf "%a _ %c _ %t _ %P\n"
```

gives the output similar to this:

```
Thu Aug 27 09:51:11 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ tempfile.tmp
```

and

```
ls -l /tmp
```

gives the output similar to this:

```
-rw-rw----+ 1 root root       5 Aug 27 04:39 tempfile.tmp
```

I'm interested only in the "+" symbol after the permissions in the ls output.

Ideally I'd like the output to be similar to this:

```
+ Thu Aug 27 09:51:11 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ tempfile.tmp
  Thu Aug 27 09:51:11 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ Thu Aug 27 09:48:40 2015 _ anothertempfile.tmp
```

Comment: Which distribution? On Ubuntu 14.04 I found `%M` mentioned in the man page, but that's only standard permissions. Looks like `find` doesn't know about extended attributes.

Comment: You'll want to look at [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/stat.1.html) and [`getfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/getfacl.1.html)

Comment: @kasperd  RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 to be specific. I think you're right, I don't see `find` having that feature in the docs and man pages I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a little script to do it for you (this is ugly but works):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
  flag="x"
  attr=$(getfattr $f)
    if [ "$attr" = "" ]
      then flag=" "
    fi
  find -name $f -printf "$flag %a _ %c _ %t _ %P\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

So write a shell script to collect your data into variables. After you have the data in variables, you can reformat and print them exactly how you want.